# How to subscribe a firebase function so that it executes via a pub/sub trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been asked to create a firebase (fb) function that triggers onUpdate. Then I have to gather a bunch of information from the fb database and publish a message so that another function triggers at that point.

fb update triggers functionA
functionA publishes a message
functionB is a subscriber to that topic and is triggered after the message publishes.

I have the basics of the onUpdate trigger below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions"),
  Promise = require("promise"),
  PubSub = require(`@google-cloud/pubsub`),
  admin = require("firebase-admin");

  const pubsub = new PubSub();

    exports.checkInOrder = functions.database
      .ref("/orders/{id}")
      .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const after = change.after.val();
        // check the status: "pending-pickup" or "fulfilled" TODO
        if (after.status === "new") {
          console.log("ended because package is new.");
          return null;
        }

        let dsObj = {};
        const orderId = context.params.id;
        const topicName = 'check-in-order';
        const subscriptionName = 'check-in-order';

        return // how would I send the message to the pubsub here?
      });
```

So to summarize:

1. How do I send a message to pubsub
2. How do I subscribe a firebase function to trigger when a topic receives a message?

If it sounds very confusing I'm sorry - I am completely lost here. Thanks!

Comment: See [Pub/Sub trigger docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) and [using Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-pub-sub) to see how to publish events to a topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Pretty straight forward, just felt overwhelmed with learning all of this stuff at once and in a rushed time frame. Below is my code. I included the whole page so in case this might help someone else out there in the future.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions"),
  Promise = require("promise"),
  PubSub = require(`@google-cloud/pubsub`),
  admin = require("firebase-admin");

const init = () => {
    const topicName = "check-in-order";
  pubsub
    .createTopic(topicName)
    .then(results => {
      const topic = results[0];
            console.log(`Topic ${topicName} created.`);
            return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
            console.error("ERROR on init:", err);
            return;
    });
};

const pubsub = new PubSub();

exports.orderCreated = functions.database
  .ref("/orders/{id}")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        console.log("it's happening!");
        const after = change.after.val();
        console.log("after::::>", after)

    if (after.status === "new") {
            console.log('stopped because status is new');
      return null;
    }

    if (after.status === "pending-pickup" || after.status === "fulfilled") {
            const orderId = context.params.id;
            const topicName = "check-in-order";
            let { assignedSlot, userId, parcelLockerId, carrier, trackingNumber, orderInDate, pickUpCode, status,  } = after;
            const dsObj = {
                order: {
                        orderId,
                        userId,
                        parcelLockerId,
                        carrier,
                        trackingNumber,
                        orderInDate,
                        pickUpCode,
                        status,
                }
         };      

            const dataBuffer = new Buffer.from(dsObj.toString());

            // publish to trigger check in function
            return pubsub
                .topic(topicName)
                .publisher()
                .publish(dataBuffer)
                .then(messageId => {
                    console.log(`:::::::: Message ${messageId} has now published. :::::::::::`);
                    return true;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error("ERROR:", err);
                    throw err;
                });
        }
        return false;
    });

exports.checkInOrder = () => {

}
exports.checkIn = functions.pubsub.topic('check-in-order').onPublish((message) => {
    console.log("everything is running now", message);
    return true;
});

init();
```